# Keep connection string open or not c#

Tags: c#, connection-string

If I have a few classes using the same connection string on the same page should I keep the connection `open();` and close it once I'm finished or keep opening and closing.

**example below**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cs.Open();
    something ...
    cs.Close();    
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cs.Open();
    something .....
    cs.Close();
}
```

**Or This**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cs.Open();
    something ...
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    something .....
    cs.Close();
    cs.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a general rule for .NET all non managed resources such as a Database Connection should be opened **as late as possible** and closed **as early as possible** so the first option you showed is the right way to do it.

.NET offers a connection pool that make sure that you do not open more connections than needed so when you call Open or Close that is not what immediately happens. But instead, the pool manages all connections you have to keep a health ratio between opening and closing communication with the database.

Unless, of course, you have some other case where you need to keep a connection open such as when you are inside a transaction.

Answer (score 5):

First, I would recommend having an abstraction that does this for you with connection and thread pooling. ADO.NET, Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc...

Second, Never .... Ever ..... Ever...... put your data access code into your page controller.

On a more practical note,

Always put your close statement into a finally block, so that it will always be called regardless of what exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Always close the connection when it is no longer in use, then re-open it when it's needed again.  Example:

```
Connection.Open();
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Connection.Close();
```

Every time you run a query, you should re-open the connection

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should release your resources once complete, and only have them open for the **shortest possible period**.  When you Open a connection, the pool is used first, so this isn't so expensive.  Just make sure your using [`connection pooling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, look at the [`using construct`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)..

```
using(var cn = new SqlConnection(...)){
 //perform db work
}
```

This will call `dispose` when you're finished.  Any class that implements the `IDisposable` interface can be used in a `Using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Open a connection to the database as late as possible, and close it as early as possible.  Following this, you should ensure that your connection is always closed.  Note that this means more than simply writing the code `connection.Close()`.  If an exception is thrown in the processing of your connection, the `Close` statement will never be hit, and your connection will remain open.

Try to use the `using` statement when dealing with unmanaged resources:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
  connection.Open();
  // do some processing
}
```

This will ensure that your connection is properly closed and disposed of.